# order of present participle before or after noun

Tags: sentence-construction

"Sports teaching at the college doesn't even approach the required standard".

This sentence has been taken from Cambridge Dictionary. To know the meaning of "approach" I searched in this dictionary and I found this sentence.

What would happen if I wrote "Teaching sports at the college..." instead of "Sports teaching at the college.."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Sports teaching' would serve as a ['compound noun'](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-compound.htm) there. But if you rewrite in your way, 'teaching' and 'sports' will make two different words.

It'd look more like **you are the teacher,** and sharing your experience as the sentence starts with *'teaching'*.

Imagine, you are a coach and you also run a private academy. Now the conversation may go like -

> "Yeah, I'm a sport teacher. I teach sport at both college and my private coaching class."
>
> "Oh, I see! Do you find any difference?"
>
> "Certainly! **Teaching sports** at the college doesn't even approach the required standard!"
>
> "Why so?"
>
> "Because of lack of required sports accessories. At my academy, I have enough of them!"

**On the other hand...**

> "Sports teaching at the college doesn't even approach the required standard".

talks about the **straight statement** i.e. your observation. Something like -

> "Healthcare has become an industry now."

Comment: "Marrying a girl does not mean that you can do everything with her whatever you want". Can I write "A girl marrying does not mean .... ......", though the meaning of it will be different? I think the later would be wrong. Because "A girl marrying" means "A girl who is going to marry" or "A girl who married". But "marrying a girl" means a male married a girl. Please tell me when word inversion like "sports teaching/teaching sports" are legal and when they are illegal.

Comment: Compound nouns are *tricky*. And, not all two different nouns put together make a *sensible compound noun*! You just discovered the one.